# typeeroor get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

so recently im trying to make a website scraper 
its mostly done all im just trying to do is just take input from user
and add it in url i am doing it like this

```py
namer = input('Enter name: ')
state = input('Enter state: ')
driver.get("https://www.example.com/people-search/"+ name,"/?state="+ state)
```

but when i try to run this code i am getting below error :

> TypeError: get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

i have tried some answers that were here posted on stackoverflow
but none of them worked

Comment: I think you want `name +`, not `name,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join string like
`driver.get("https://www.example.com/people-search/"+namer+"/?state="+ state)`